# Filtering based on key/value in all objects in array in RethinkDB

Tags: javascript, database, rethinkdb, nosql

I have a RethinkDB table with records structured like this:

```
{
 one: [
  {
   field: val,
   foo: bar
  },
  {
   field: val2
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, if I do something like

```
reql = reql.filter(function(tb) {
                    return tb("one").contains(function(k) {
                            return k("field").eq(val);
                    });
        });
```

I match all documents where *one of the objects* in the array on the key "one" has a key "field" with a value matching "val". However, what I want to do is to only match the documents where *all of* the objects in the array on the key "one" have keys "field" with values matching "val".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each element of the array to a boolean (whether the value for "field" is "val"), then reduce with a `and`.

So something like this:

```
reql.filter(function(tb) {
    return tb("one").map(function(element) {
        return element("field").eq("val")
    }).reduce(function(left, right) {
        return left.and(right)
    })
})
```

Comment: how is this snippet in python? @neumino